# Using a stack to determine if an expression has balanced parentheses

Tags: c++, stack

I am working on my last school assignment for the semester and we are being introduced to stacks for the first time but I am having an issue with my program not analyzing the expression properly. Everything executes but the program always comes out with the result that expression is unbalanced. Any clues to point me in the right direction?

```
//    
//  main.cpp
//  Balanced Parenthesis
#include "StringStack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
StringStack stack;
char entry;
    int parCounter = 0;
cout << "This program will accept a string and determine whether it has balanced        parenthesis.\n";
cout << "Please type a sentence to be analyzed\n";

while (cin.get (entry) && entry != '\n')
{
            stack.push(entry);

}
if (stack.isEmpty()) {
    cout << "The stack is empty./n";
}

else{
    stack.pop(entry);
    if (entry == ')') {
        parCounter++;
    }
    else if(entry == '('){
        parCounter--;
    }


}
if (parCounter > 0 || parCounter < 0){
            cout << "This expression has UNBALANCED parentheses\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "This expression has BALANCED parentheses\n";

    }



return 0;
}

//  StringStack.h
//  Balanced Par

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef StringStack_h
#define StringStack_h


//Define our stack class and its contents
class StringStack
{
private:

    char *stackArray;
    int stackSize;
    char top;
public:
StringStack();
    ~StringStack() {delete[] stackArray;}
    void push(char);
    void pop(char &);
    bool isBalanced();
    bool isEmpty();
};

#endif

//Constructor
StringStack::StringStack()
{
    stackArray = new char[stackSize];
    top = 0;
}

//Function to determine if stack is empty.
bool StringStack::isEmpty()
{
    if (top == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Function to push letters/puncuation onto the stack
void StringStack::push(char letter)
{
//if (isEmpty())
{
    top++;
    stackArray[top] = letter;
}
//else
//{
    //exit(1);
//}
}

//Function to pop letters/puncuation off the stack
void StringStack::pop(char &letter)
{
if (isEmpty())
{
    cout << "The stack is empty.\n";
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    letter = stackArray[top];
    top--;
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the stack to store the entire input string itself. Your algorithm can be bettered. Since it's your assignment, I'll let you think over it.

Comment: Where is the definition of StringStack::isBalanced method? On the other hand, you having the same number of '(' and ')'n don't ensure balanced parentheses.

Comment: I recommend you read some doc about **infix** and **postfix** expressions and then rewrite your code in order to do it the right way.

Answer (score 2):

You're not initialising or setting the member `stackSize` anywhere. This makes `new char[stackSize]` undefined behaviour and anything could happen.

And after you fix that, you're only inspecting the **top** of the stack. You need a loop around the `parCount` - controlling `if` to run until the stack is empty.